# Programmatically insert pictures into a pdf using vtl and fop

Tags: pdf, apache-fop, vtl

I am trying to generate a pdf with images from a url. The url is a protected path.

The FO.vtl template is as follows:

```
<fo:table-row>
  <fo:table-cell>
    #if($photos.size() > 0)
      #foreach($photo in $photos)
        #set ($urly = "https://example.com/image?userId=${user.id}&amp;photoId=${photo.id}")
        <fo:external-graphic
          src="url('${urly}')"
        />
      #end
    #end
  </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

I get the following Error in the console:

```
 Error while creating area : Error while recovering Image Informations (https://example.com/image?userId=12312&photoId=232) : domain.com
```

The FOP is super old. I think it's 1.0.

Comment: Is updating the FOP jar you are using an option? The problem you are experiencing could be a bug already fixed in recent versions.

Comment: Turns out the version is actually 0.20.5! Anyway I went ahead and swapped in the 2.6 jar which is the most updated one and I still get the same behavior. Is it possible it's because the image is a protected path? Does the path need a jpeg extension?

Comment: What do you mean with "protected path"? If the url requires authentication, you could try with https://username:password@example.com/image?...

Comment: As in you need to login to an account in order to access the image url.